# Calling a Non-Static Method in a Null Object JAVA?

Tags: java, null

```
**public void testCompareTo() {
    System.out.println("compareTo");
    Patient p = null;
    Patient instance = null;
    int expResult = 0;
    int result = instance.compareTo(p);
    assertEquals(expResult, result);
}**
```

**Is there a way to call a method in a null object or do I have to do an Exception here?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't call a non-static method on a null object, since that would cause a `NullPointerException`.

You must verify that `instance` is not null before calling `instance.compareTo(p)`.

Comment: Actually, semantically this is not true. What you mean is that calling any method on a null object will ALWAYS throw a NullPointerException

Comment: Is there a way to set a value for the variable "result"?.If I can't call compareTo and without changing the values of and 'p' and 'instance'

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That's interesting to know. I never tried to call a static method through a null object reference. Then again, I try not to call static methods though an object reference, so it's not a surprise I never tried it.

Comment: @user3133474 You can initialize it to a default value and then assign to it the result of `compareTo` if `instance != null`. Or you can use the new Optional class introduced in Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

`null` objects by definition are... nothing. You can't invoke an instance level method on a null object without causing a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: *"You can't invoke anything on a null object without causing a `NullPointerException`"* You can, you know: A *static* method. (Bizarre but true.)

Comment: You're technically invoking the method on the Class, not the object.

Comment: Yes, quite true. You're using the variable/data member (e.g., that's how the compiler figures out what class is relevant), but not an *object*.

Comment: Having just tested it, I didn't realize that at run time, a null instance.someStaticMethod() won't cause a NPE. Learned something today.... something... pretty useless :).

Comment: It is indeed (useless, I mean). :-) The bytecode even goes to the trouble of reading the value from the variable first, before...not using it.

Comment: @EdwardSmith - Actually, its the reference that points to `null`. There isn't an object involved here. :)

Comment: @TheLostMind I think it's fairly clear that when I say "null object" I am referring to an object reference which is null. Kind of splitting hairs, don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

NullPointerException is inevitable in this case as java can not get any reference from a null object, which makes it obvious to throw a NullPointerException